# Redirect user input to /dev/null

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Hi I'm trying to implement a chat client - server, and want all client's entered text to not be printed locally on the client. 
So once the user hits enter, the data should be sent to the server only and not to STDOUT. The server then should send this data back to me and all other clients, and only then display this data.

Is this possible ?

When not doing any manipulation on FD I just get duplicate data, and when trying to redirect STDOUT to /dev/null - I still see the user input data on the screen.(after enter key is hit I just want it to clear the screen, maybe?)

With this code I get two lines of output:

```
void * rcv_from_srv_thread(void * sock_fd_ptr)
{
    char recv_buf[BUF_SIZE] = {};
    int len = 0;
    int sock_fd = *(int *)sock_fd_ptr;


    while (1)
    {
        if ((len = recv(sock_fd, recv_buf, BUF_SIZE, 0)) < 0)
        {
            perror("recv failed");
            return NULL;
        }

        recv_buf[len] = '\0';
        printf("%s", recv_buf);

    }

    assert(0);
    return NULL;

}

void * send_to_srv_thread(void * sock_fd_ptr)
{
    char send_buf[BUF_SIZE] = {};
    int len;
    int sock_fd = *(int *)sock_fd_ptr;

    do
    {
        fgets(send_buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin);

        if ((len = send(sock_fd, send_buf, strlen(send_buf), 0)) < 0)
        {
            perror("send failed");
            return NULL;
        }

    } while(1);

    assert(0);
    return NULL;
}
```

When running the client:

```
root@sergey-VirtualBox:~/chat/client# ./client
aaaa
got server IP - 127.0.0.1
asdasd
asdasd
ddd
ddd
```

Comment: You have to tell the terminal to disable *echo*. This is usually done with [the termios function family](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html).

Comment: I would rather say, it is usually done with the ncurses library API. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: Or perhaps even more appropriate: Have a look at _libreadline_ or its wrapper-binary `rlwrap`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Then how can the user know what he has entered?

Comment: "*client's entered text to not be printed locally on the client*" so you want the user to *blindly* type in his/her message? Really?

Comment: The fundamental confusion here is caused by the all to common belief that stdin is a tty.  Stop conflating the two.  What the user types is *not* being written to stdout.  it is being displayed on the screen prior to being written to the client's stdin.

Comment: @alk No, I want him to see. Just once the Enter key is pressed - I don't want it to be printed on screen

Comment: From a usability perspective I feel it's odd, that I could see what I typed just only after I cannot edit it anymore.

Comment: Its my first attempt to implement such client - server, maybe later I will try to improve it - thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is maybe not the best or cleanest, but at least probably the easiest. You just move up the cursor one line after fgets was run and to the beginning, and the entered line will be overwritten:

```
// fgets(…)
printf("%c[A\r", 27);

// …
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the cursor up, then clear the entire line before printing

```
#define CSI "\x1B["
printf(CSI "F" CSI "2K");
printf("This is a message.\n");
```